# Wrap AsciiDoc content inside a block/container and assign a class or id to it

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I want to wrap partial content inside any block or container so that I can reference it in CSS.

So far I have tried to wrap the content in an open block and assiging a custom id attribute to it.

```
= My document

Lorem ipsum

[id="changelog"]
--

== Changelog

* Foo
* Bar

--
```

It works but the section or heading (`Changelog` in this case) is not being rendered properly.

P.S I am using AsciiDoctor by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my question, it is possible to wrap content in a open block but the titles/sections/headings will not be parsed because it violates the document structure rules.

A simple work around is to use the [`discrete`](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#discrete-headings) style to make it a regular heading, and thus it will render correctly:

```
= My document

Lorem ipsum

[id="changelog"]
--

[discrete]
== Changelog

* Foo
* Bar

--
```

---

A better way to do this is to use a table block and fit the content into a table cell with the AsciiDoc style which will accept all AsciiDoc syntax to be rendered

We can id the table and reference it in CSS like shown in this example:

```
= My document

Lorem ipsum

++++
<style>
/* Hide the table's style */

#changelog {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#changelog tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
++++

[id="changelog"]
|===
a|

== Changelog

* Foo
* Bar

|===
```

This is especially useful when using the [`include`](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-directive) directive where you cannot modify the included file itself and you want to control the content block using CSS.